# Cannot match following node of ancestor in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML like this:

```
<table>
<tr class="mergedrow">
<th scope="row"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Austria" title="Telephone numbers in Austria">Area code</a></th>
<td>07236</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to get the area code: 07236.
What I did until now is to match the "< a >" node with: 
//*[text() = "Area code"]

Now I need to get the sibling of the ancestor node < th scope="row"> which is the < td> node.
The reason why I chose to match directly on text was because the table is huge, hundreds of lines.

I tried //* [text() = "Area code"]/../ancestor::th to at least match the ancestor
and also //* [text() = "Area code"]/../following::td. They both do not work.

I am a newbie with XPath, so I apologise if the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```
//th[normalize-space() = 'Area code']/following-sibling::td/text()
```

will select the `"07236"` text node child of the `td` element following the `th` whose space normalized string value is `"Area code"`, as requested.

Comment: I agree that it works with the specific short example I gave, but with the whole xml file it does not match. I am going to try some more and get back to you. Thanks alot btw.

Comment: Sure, if you explain specifically how it doesn't work for the real case -- error messages, wrong/extra nodes selected, etc -- we can try to refine the XPath to cover it.  Expanding the example to cover the relevant extra markup would be ideal.

Comment: My current problem is that the XML contains xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" as a namespace in a <html> tag. If I delete that it works. I am trying to figure out how to make it work even with this namespace.

Comment: I found it. I am using KNIME, a data analytics tools which executes nodes that can do all sort of things. When executing the XPath nodes, the namespace I wrote in my previous comment was stored under "dns". So my final XPath expression was: //dns:*[text()="Area code"]/../following-sibling::dns:td.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. I am using KNIME, a data analytics tools which executes nodes that can do all sort of things. When executing the XPath nodes, the namespace I wrote in my previous comment was stored under "dns". So my final XPath expression was: //dns:*[text()="Area code"]/../following-sibling::dns:td.